# text binary classification error:logits and labels must have the same shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to bulid a model to classify my text to hate (1) or not (0) using nn.

Information about the data, it's consists of tweets and class label (hate (1) or not (0)):

```
sentences = df['comment']
y = df['isHate']

sentences_train, sentences_test, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(sentences, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```

the text get through a lot of Word Embeddings and I applied pad sequences on the tweets and LabelEncoder on the labels.

the problem is when I do the run I get this error:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 2))
```

the code of the model:

```
emb_dim = 16

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim= emb_dim, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

the problem happened in this part:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=32,
                    epochs=15,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Your last dense layer has only 1 unit but your labels are one hot encoded which consist of 2 classes. So you need to change:

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

You also need to change your loss function, because they are **one-hot-encoded**:

```
loss='categorical_crossentropy'
```

Comment: I'd rather go with undoing the one-hot encoding and changing nothing else, otherwise the Tensorflow devs created `binary_crossentropy` for nothing. Also, don't beg for votes when your answer has already been accepted. That's vote manipulation